# Are all Mordell equations $y^2=x^3+k$, for any integer $k$, solvable

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

Are all Mordell equations $y^2=x^3+k$, for any integer $k$, solvable? Not that there are solutions $x,y$ for every $k$, but that you can determine for every $k$ if there are solutions, and if there are, what those solutions are. That is also considering that you have a finite amount of time to solve them.

Comment: Are you asking whether there exists an algorithm whose input is $k$, and whose output is a description of all solutions to $y^2 = x^3 + k$?

Comment: Yes, or if there could even ever exist such an algorithm

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there are algorithms for finding all integer solutions to any elliptic curve over the rationals.

See, for example, the paper [Solving elliptic diophantine equations:
the general cubic case](http://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5b29%5dStdW-EllCubic-ActaArith%5b1999%5d.pdf).

In particular, the authors mention explicit upper bounds for integer solutions, so in principle we can find all integer solutions just by checking a finite list.  There are more practical algorithms out there, of course, but this gives an affirmative answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem by Baker (see [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2008/mordell.pdf), page $20$): If $y^2=x^3+k$ for some $x,y,k\in\Bbb Z, k\neq 0$, then $$\max\{|x|,|y|\}\le \left(e^{10^{10}}\right)^{|k|^{10\, 000}}$$

Practically, it's not solvable for all $k\in\Bbb Z_{\neq 0}$ because of computer power/time constraints. Mordell's equation is fully solved when $0<|k|\le 10^4$ and for some $10^4<|k|\le 10^5$, but not when $|k|>10^5$. See [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1000281602647) from $1998$ (i.e. written only $17$ years ago).