# $x^2+k=y^3$ no integral solution

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $k > 0$ be a squarefree positive integer and $k = 1, 2 \mod(4)$. Suppose there exists no integer $a$ s.t. $k = 3a^2 \pm 1$. Additionally, $3$ should not divide the class number of $\mathbb Q (\sqrt{-k})$.

Why does then the equation $x^2 + k = y^3$ have no integral solution?

Comment: See for [Mordell curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549066/are-all-mordell-equations-y2-x3k-for-any-integer-k-solvable) on this site. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174845/for-which-small-n-is-unknown-whether-the-mordell-curve-has-an-integral-point?rq=1). A solution is given [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-4819-5_15). In Theorem $I$, part $(B)$ is the assumption that the class number is not divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is well-known, and can be found on the web. See for example http://faculty.csuci.edu/brian.sittinger/mordell.pdf

I only sketch the proof. Let $I=(x-\sqrt{-k})$ and $J=(x+\sqrt{-k})$, so that $IJ=(y)^3$.
One may show that $I$ and $J$ are coprime (this is a bit of work...)

By uniqueness of decomposition into produts of powers of prime ideals, $I$ and $J$ are cubes of some ideals. Write $I=(x-\sqrt{-k}))=K^3$.
Since the class group has no element of order $3$ by assumption, $K$ is principal ideal, i.e. $K=(z)$. We then have $z^3=\pm(x-\sqrt{-k})$ (units here are equal to $\pm 1$). A bit of algebra and the assumption on $k$ then shows that you have no solution.