# Class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-37})$ and integer solutions to the equation $x^2+37=y^3$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am preparing for an exam in Algebraic number theory and I wanted to solve the following exercise:

a) Find the class group $\mathrm{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ of the field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-37})$.

b) Determine the complete set of the integer solutions to the equation $$x^2+37=y^3$$

I have successfully proven that $\mathrm{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_K)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Now, for the second part of the exercise, after a little investigation I have concluded that if $(x,y)$ is an integer solution then $x$ must be even and $y$ must be odd by assuming the opposite and then going modulo $8$ to arrive at a contradiction but after that I am getting lost. I know a method of examining whether there are or not integer solutions to the equation $x^2 +d=y^3$ when $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is a UFD. Although, this is not the case for our $d=-37$ since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-37}]$ is not a UFD.

Also, I have the same problem with the exercise:

-Determine the complete set of the integer solutions to the equation $$x^2+11=y^3$$

Finally, I know that the equations above are strongly related to elliptic curves but I cannot use such arguments.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466879/x2k-y3-no-integral-solution/3466923#3466923

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed very helpful. Should we mark this quastion somehow or should I delete it? Since the other question solves the problem this one seems unnesseary.

Comment: How do you conclude from $z^3=\pm(x-\sqrt{-k})$ ?

Comment: In my case, i.e. $k=37$, if you set $z=a+b\sqrt{-37}$ then you conclude from the fact that $\mathcal{O}_K$ has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $\{1, \sqrt{-37}\}$.

Comment: I had to squint, and now I have to ask to make sure: the square of $x$ plus $37$ is the *cube* of $y$? Did I read that correctly?

Comment: @Mr.Brooks Yes, you read that correctly.