# How to check if a number can be represented as difference of a cube and sqaure?

Tags: sequences-and-series, square-numbers

How to check if a number can be represented as difference of a cube and square ?

For eg. $18 = 27 - 9$. Hence $18$ can be represented as difference of a cube and square.

Comment: Why do you think there is a simple characterization ?

Comment: You might be interested in the reference at http://oeis.org/A002938

Comment: but how  to check condition

Answer (score 3):

This can be computed by the so-called **Mordell curve**, the elliptic curve
$$
y^2=x^3+k.
$$
For a reference see the notes by [K. Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf), or the references here at MSE:

[Are all Mordell equations $y^2=x^3+k$, for any integer $k$, solvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549066/are-all-mordell-equations-y2-x3k-for-any-integer-k-solvable)

[Solutions to $y^2 = x^3 + k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107144/solutions-to-y2-x3-k)

Comment: This is the first time the relationship has occurred to me, two squares minus a cube give everything:   http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Elkies_Kap.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Ah, very interesting. I wasn't aware of it, too. Perhaps we'll see  this soon here as a new question.

Comment: Interesting material. More in http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Experimental_1995.pdf    where we informed Vaughan early enough for him to put our main example in the second edition of his book on the Hardy Littlewood method. We had not known about this, Kevin Ford told us that we had disproved an existing conjecture which was recorded in Vaughan's first edition.